# How to get the state of a service with sd-bus?

Tags: c++, systemd, dbus

I need to query, monitor and possibly change the state of a few systemd services from a C++ application.  It looks like sd-bus is the right way to do this, but I'm having a terrible time finding an example.

So, how do I:

1) Query the current status of a service via sd-bus, similar to `systemctl status foo.service`?

2) Monitor the status of a service such that I get a callback whenever it changes?

3) Change the status of a service, similar to `systemctl start/stop/restart`?

Thanks!

Comment: This is pretty big question (or three)... For an example of sd-bus usage of systemd1 API, you could look at systemctl itself (in systemd source code) -- I'll warn that it's a huge tool so might not be very easy to follow. As far as D-Bus libraries go, sd-bus is a fairly low-level API and GDBus (or even Qt) are likely to be easier to use. I suggest you pick a library and read the manual: you should then be able to use that knowledge with systemd1 API and ask specific questions if needed. For debugging and testing I suggest playing around with d-feet.

Comment: For the specific systemd1 API, see https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/dbus/, especially the "Unit Objects" section: the Start() and Stop() methods and LoadState and Substate properties should be of interest

Comment: sd-bus is absolutely the way to do it.  There's a fantastic blog post about that here: http://0pointer.de/blog/the-new-sd-bus-api-of-systemd.html.  I'll post an example tomorrow.  I have a bit of an answer to this in my question here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/527283/watching-sd-bus-properties/527350#527350.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using the `sd-bus` API is absolutely correct (header `#include <systemd/sd-bus.h>`)

First you need get access to a bus object:

I do this:

```
Systemctl::Systemctl() :
    m_bus(nullptr)
{
    int r = sd_bus_default_system(&m_bus);

    if (r < 0)
        throw exception("Could not open systemd bus");
}
```

If you're having problems opening the bus:

1. Run as root/sudo
2. Make some polkit policies to grant your user/group access to this command
3. Run the `_user` bus instead of the `_system` bus

Don't forget to release the bus when you are done:

```
Systemctl::~Systemctl()
{
    sd_bus_unref(m_bus);
}
```

Now you had 3 questions:

1. Query the status

For each unit, I have a class which holds the escaped name (`foo_2eservice`) as `m_name`, and a reference to the bus in `m_bus`.  Call this method with any property.  You seem to be most interested in `"ActiveState"` or `"SubState"`.

```
std::string Unit::GetPropertyString(const std::string& property) const
{
    sd_bus_error err = SD_BUS_ERROR_NULL;
    char* msg = nullptr;
    int r;

    r = sd_bus_get_property_string(m_bus,
        "org.freedesktop.systemd1",
        ("/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/" + m_unit).c_str(),
        "org.freedesktop.systemd1.Unit",
        property.c_str(),
        &err,
        &msg);

    if (r < 0)
    {
        std::string err_msg(err.message);
        sd_bus_error_free(&err);

        std::string err_str("Failed to get " + property + " for service "
                            + m_name + ". Error: " + err_msg);

        throw exception(err_str);
    }

    sd_bus_error_free(&err);

    // Free memory (avoid leaking)
    std::string ret(msg);
    free (msg);

    return ret;
}
```

2. Monitor the status of a service:

The first step is to set up a file-descriptor to subscribe to changes.  In this case you are interested in subscribing to the "PropertiesChanged" signal.  Note that you'll get a signal for any property changing, not just the state.  In the `sd_bus_add_match()` call, there is room for a callback, though I haven't experimented with it.

```
void Systemctl::SubscribeToUnitChanges(const std::string& escaped_name)
{
    /* This function is an easier helper, but it as only introduced in systemd 237
     * Stretch is on 232 while buster is on 241 .  Need re replace this as long as
     * we still support stretch
    sd_bus_match_signal(
        m_bus,
        nullptr, // slot
        nullptr, // sender
        std::string("/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/" + escaped_name).c_str(), // path
        "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties", // interface
        "PropertiesChanged", // member
        nullptr, // callback
        nullptr // userdata
    );
    */
    std::string match =  "type='signal'";
        match += ",path='/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/" + escaped_name + "'" ;
        match += ",interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties'";
        match += ",member='PropertiesChanged'";

    sd_bus_add_match(
        m_bus,
        nullptr, // slot
        match.c_str(),
        nullptr, // callback
        nullptr // userdata
    );
}
```

Instead what I do is periodically poll the bus for the subscribed changes and update each unit:

```
bool Systemctl::ProcessBusChanges()
{
    bool changed = false;
    sd_bus_message* msg = nullptr;

    // for each new message
    std::list<std::string> escaped_names;
    while( sd_bus_process(m_bus, &msg) )
    {
        // Note:  Once sd_bus_process returns 0, We are supposed to call
        // sd_bus_wait, or check for changes on sd_bus_get_fd before calling
        // this function again.  We're breaking that rule.  I don't really know
        // the consequences.
        if (msg)
        {
            std::string path = strna( sd_bus_message_get_path(msg) );
            sd_bus_message_unref(msg);

            std::string escaped_name = path.erase(0, path.find_last_of('/')+1 );
            escaped_names.push_back(escaped_name);

            changed = true;
        }
    }

    escaped_names.sort();
    escaped_names.unique();
    for (auto unit : escaped_names)
    {
        auto it = m_units.find(unit);
        if (it != m_units.end())
            it->second.RefreshDynamicProperties();
    }

    return changed;
}
```

If it tells us that the bus has changed, then I go ahead and read all of my monitored units on that bus.

3. Change the status

This one is easy.  I use the following, where `method` is one of `"StartUnit"`, `"StopUnit"`, or `"RestartUnit"`.

```
static void CallMethodSS(sd_bus* bus,
                         const std::string& name,
                         const std::string& method)
{
    sd_bus_error err = SD_BUS_ERROR_NULL;
    sd_bus_message* msg = nullptr;
    int r;

    r = sd_bus_call_method(bus,
        "org.freedesktop.systemd1",         /* <service>   */
        "/org/freedesktop/systemd1",        /* <path>      */
        "org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager", /* <interface> */
        method.c_str(),                     /* <method>    */
        &err,                               /* object to return error in */
        &msg,                               /* return message on success */
        "ss",                               /* <input_signature (string-string)> */
        name.c_str(),  "replace" );         /* <arguments...> */

    if (r < 0)
    {
        std::string err_str("Could not send " + method +
                            " command to systemd for service: " + name +
                            ". Error: " + err.message );

        sd_bus_error_free(&err);
        sd_bus_message_unref(msg);
        throw exception(err_str);
    }

    // Extra stuff that might be useful:  display the response...
    char* response;
    r = sd_bus_message_read(msg, "o", &response);
    if (r < 0)
    {
      LogError("Failed to parse response message: %s\n", strerror(-r) );
    }

    sd_bus_error_free(&err);
    sd_bus_message_unref(msg);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a complete example somewhere, like on github?